# How to redirect http to https EC2 windows instance of AWS?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, https, elastic-load-balancer

I have implemented SSL on my EC2 Windows instance. As AWS doesn't directly allow to configure SSL on EC2 instance, so I created a Load Balancer with HTTPS and configure my SSL certificate with it. I have selected my EC2 instance for Load Balancer.

Following are the listeners of my Load Balancer:
[image: Load Balancer Listeners]

After this configuration, my domain starts working on http and also on https like http://example.com and https://example.com

Now, I want to redirect http request to https. My domain is on Godaddy. I have successfully change DNS and they are working. But when I place URL rewrite code in web.config file then both of my URLs stop working. It gives HTTP error 503

Answer (score 0):

This link outlines some great options - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/05/22/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher/